# Kubuntu update yeilds, "no metadata URIs for vendor-directory"

Tags: updates, kubuntu, discover-software-center

Kubuntu 22.04 with backports (upgraded from Kubuntu 20.04 with backports).

When I use Discover to install updates, I get a momentary pop-up in the Discover window that reads "no metadata URIs for vendor-directory".

No log files seem to be left behind and this does not occur when updating in the terminal. Nothing seems to go awry.

Could this indicate a real problem?  Is there a way to fix or prevent this?

Google search on the string turns up nothing but irrelevant hits.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could this indicate a real problem?

If your updates are working fine through terminal there is nothing to worry about.

> Is there a way to fix or prevent this?

You can try the following steps if you want to use "Discover" to install updates.

1. Open Discover and go to the Updates tab.
2. In the Updates tab, click on the Settings button in the top right
   corner of the window.
3. In the Settings window, go to the "Updates" section and click on the
   "Advanced" button.
4. In the Advanced settings window, go to the "Metadata" section and
   check the "Use vendor-provided metadata" option.
5. Click on the "Apply" button to save your changes and close the
   Settings window.

Comment: Discover UI presents itself on my machine very differently from what you describe.  To try to see what you apparently see, I installed Kubuntu 22.04 in a VM.  While Discover didn't look any different that the host machine, it also didn't have the issue.  I then compared /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ between the two, and found only one mention of a URI and that was on the host - WINEHQ.  Purging and reinstalling WINE stopped the notification.  Apparently, updating from 20.04 to 22.04 disables all repositories except WINE.

Comment: @Utkarsh So, for those of us that still have the issue and have 3rd party in sources.list.d/ how do we add that vendor metadata switch? Because my software centre is different, too. Must be something changeable via clii!